# Implicits in Ordering

Tags: scala

In the Ordering trait we can find this implicit method:

```
/** This implicit method augments `T` with the comparison operators defined
* in `scala.math.Ordering.Ops`.
*/
implicit def mkOrderingOps(lhs: T): Ops = new Ops(lhs)
```

And in the companion object Ordering.Implicits one can find:

```
/** This implicit creates a conversion from any value for which an
  * implicit `Ordering` exists to the class which creates infix operations.
  * With it imported, you can write methods as follows:
  *
  * {{{
  * def lessThan[T: Ordering](x: T, y: T) = x < y
  * }}}
  */
implicit def infixOrderingOps[T](x: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[T]#Ops = new ord.Ops(x)
```

Is this second implicit really necessary? In what context one should use the first implicit and in what context should one use the second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first implicit can only be used in scope of `Ordering` (it isn't), in scope of any types extending `Ordering`, or by being directly imported:

```
def foo[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) = {
  import ord.mkOrderingOps

  x < y
}
```

Note that 1) to import it you need to have a name for the ordering in first place (unlike in `def lessThan[T: Ordering](x: T, y: T) = ...`); 2) if you have two orderings for different types in scope, you can't import `mkOrderingOps` from both without renaming it: `import ord1.mkOrderingOps; import ord2.{mkOrderingOps => mkOrderingOps2}`.
The second method has neither of these problems.

What I don't know is 1) why you would use the first implicit (maybe it was introduced before the second one?); 2) why the second one isn't defined in `scala.Predef` so that you could just use the operators without importing anything.